# what is unconditional self loop in promela?

Tags: distributed-computing, model-checking, promela, spin

I am working on a project which involves SPIN Model checker.SPIN version 6.4.7 and ispin version 1.1.4 I am getting this error on ispin saying

> state 76: unconditional self loop

```
    proctype TDMAProtocol(byte id; chan P1, P2, PR)

54  { 

55       byte id_j, members_j, r_j;

56     do 

57        ::nodeState[id].r == id ->  
58           nodeState[id].r =  (nodeState[id].r + 1) % 4;

59  
60        atomic {  
61  //       printf("-- %d New round %d member %d cmembers %d\n" , id, nodeState[id].r,nodeState[id].members, nodeState[id].cmembers);

62        
63           nodeState[id].r =  (nodeState[id].r + 1) % 4;

64           nodeState[id].messageLost[0] = nodeState[id].messageLost[0]+1;

65           nodeState[id].messageLost[1] = nodeState[id].messageLost[1]+1;

66           nodeState[id].messageLost[2] = nodeState[id].messageLost[2]+1;

67           nodeState[id].messageLost[id] = 0;

68  //       nodeState[id].round = 1;
69       
70            // Send aloha
71            if    
72            ::nodeState[id].state == ALOHA && nodeState[id].p == 0 -> 
73              
74  //            printf("%d --Sending \n" , id);
75                P1!id,nodeState[id].members,nodeState[id].r;  
76                P2!id,nodeState[id].members,nodeState[id].r;
77                 if 
78                    ::true ->  nodeState[id].p = 0;
79                    ::true ->  nodeState[id].p = 1;
80                    ::skip
81                fi;             
82            ::nodeState[id].state == ALOHA && nodeState[id].p == 1 -> 
83                if 
84                ::true ->  nodeState[id].p = 0;
85                ::true ->  nodeState[id].p = 1
86                fi;
87  //            printf("%d --Sending with proabality %d\n" , id, nodeState[id].p);
88                
89          // send TDMA
90            ::nodeState[id].state != ALOHA -> 
91  //          printf("%d --Sending TDM\n" , id)
92              
93              P1!id,nodeState[id].members,nodeState[id].r;  
94              P2!id,nodeState[id].members,nodeState[id].r 
95            ::skip
96            
97            fi;
98        }    
99      
100      :: empty(PR) ->
101           skip
102      :: nempty(PR) ->
103        PR?id_j,members_j,r_j;
104 //     printf("%d Size of channel %d\n", id, len(PR));
105        atomic {
106          if 
107           ::nodeState[id].state ==  ALOHA ->
108           nodeState[id].messageLost[id_j] = 0;
109           nodeState[id].members = nodeState[id].members | (1 << id_j); 
110           if 
111             ::nodeState[id].members == members_j ->
112               nodeState[id].cmembers = nodeState[id].members | (1 << id_j)
113             ::skip
114           fi;
115           if 
116             ::nodeState[id].cmembers == members_j ->
117               printf("%d reaches TDMA\n", id);
118               nodeState[id].state = TDMA
119               if 
120             ::nodeState[id].leader > members_j -> 
121               nodeState[id].leader = members_j
122             ::skip
123               fi;
124               if 
125             ::nodeState[id].leader == members_j -> 
126               nodeState[id].r = r_j
127             ::skip
128               fi;
129              ::nodeState[id].cmembers != members_j ->
130             skip
131           fi;
132 //         printf("%d --Receiving in ALOHA %d from %d\n" , id,  nodeState[id].members, id_j);
133 
134         ::nodeState[id].state !=  ALOHA -> 
135 //      printf("%d reaches TDMA\n" , id);
136         nodeState[id].messageLost[id_j] = 0
137          
138         fi; 
139       } 
140       //round
141          // Failure detector 
142      :: nodeState[id].state == TDMA && 
143           (nodeState[id].messageLost[0] > 3 || nodeState[id].messageLost[1] > 3 || nodeState[id].messageLost[2] > 3) ->
144           atomic {
145         printf("%d ALOHA from failure Detector\n", id);
146 
147         nodeState[id].state = ALOHA;
148         nodeState[id].members = 1 << id;
149         nodeState[id].cmembers = 1 << id;
150         nodeState[id].leader = id
151           } 
152 //   :: nodeState[id].round > 0 ->   
153 //      nodeState[id].round = (nodeState[id].round + 1) % 2
154      :: nodeState[id].r != id ->
155        // printf("%d in round %d\n" , id, nodeState[id].r);
156         nodeState[id].r =  (nodeState[id].r + 1) % 4
157         
158         //nodeState[id].round = (nodeState[id].round + 1) % 2
159      :: skip
160    od;
161 }
```

Error is pointed at line 57.I am not sure what does this mean. when i run my code on terminal it works fine bt with ispin interface it throws this error. Someone came across this error?

Comment: Which version of the SPIN distribution generated this error? Searching for "unconditional self loop" in the files of [`spin647.tar.gz`](http://spinroot.com/spin/Src/spin647.tar.gz) did not return any result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after spending many hours wandering around the code. i tried hit and trial and removed last skip statement from the model. Seems like many possible alternative guard statements along with additional skip statement made it an unconditional self loop.
It worked when i removed the last **::skip** statement from **do loop**.

---

It appears that `Spin` has some very simple mechanism for detecting *unconditional self loops* caused by some loop guard being equal to `skip` or `true` with no subsequent *instruction* to be executed, **e.g.**:

```cpp
init
{
    do
        :: skip            // or true
    od;
}
```

prints:

```sh
~$ spin -search test.pml 
error: proctype ':init:' line 4, state 2: has unconditional self-loop

pan: elapsed time 1.76e+07 seconds
pan: rate         0 states/second
```

The routine can be easily circumvented by adding an extra empty statement:

```cpp
init
{
    do
        :: skip -> skip            // or true -> true
    od;
}
```

prints:

```sh
~$ spin -search test.pml 

(Spin Version 6.4.3 -- 16 December 2014)
    + Partial Order Reduction

Full statespace search for:
    never claim             - (none specified)
    assertion violations    +
    cycle checks            - (disabled by -DSAFETY)
    invalid end states      +

State-vector 12 byte, depth reached 1, errors: 0
        2 states, stored
        1 states, matched
        3 transitions (= stored+matched)
        0 atomic steps
hash conflicts:         0 (resolved)

Stats on memory usage (in Megabytes):
    0.000   equivalent memory usage for states (stored*(State-vector + overhead))
    0.292   actual memory usage for states
  128.000   memory used for hash table (-w24)
    0.534   memory used for DFS stack (-m10000)
  128.730   total actual memory usage


unreached in init
    test.pml:6, state 6, "-end-"
    (1 of 6 states)

pan: elapsed time 0 seconds
```

Interestingly, the routine fails to consider other obvious cases in which an *unconditional self-loop* arises, **e.g.** when the guard is a number different from `0` and there is no re-entrant block of instructions.